# Woocommerce global percentage discount on simple products if customer is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, discount

I'm looking for advice on what's wrong with the following function.

My goal in this example is to apply a 50% off discount to all WooCommerce simple products, as long as the user is logged in.

```
function tier_pricing_logic() {  

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  

        function assign_tier_pricing( $price, $product ) {
            $price = $price * 0.5; // Set all prices for simple products to 50% off.    
        }   
        return $price; 

        add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
        add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );     
    }

}                  
add_action( 'init', 'tier_pricing_logic' );
```

This function has no effect on the prices, am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: FYI there are a variety of plugins for Woo that let you do discounts. Why roll your own when you can manage it from a plugin?

Comment: Well it's actually because this function issue is just part of a larger set of conditions that I can't seem to pull off with the plugins out there.

Comment: There should be something in [link](https://businessbloomer.com/apply-store-wide-bulk-discounts-woocommerce/) here that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you don't need the `init` hook and your IF statement needs to be inside the hooked function, so try that instead (for simple products):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
function assign_tier_pricing( $price, $product ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $product->is_type('simple') ) { 
        $price *= 0.5; // Set all prices for simple products to 50% off.    
    }   
    return $price;   
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thanks so much! I have to learn how to nest my functions properly!