# Woocommerce global percentage discount for all product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

don't know how i can create global percentage discount for all product for all ppl
Mb same body know how i can do it? mb same body have same code what i can put in function.php
P.S. I find same but for simple product and for logginet users [Woocommerce global percentage discount on simple products if customer is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798268/woocommerce-global-percentage-discount-on-simple-products-if-customer-is-logged) but need for all and for all product

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the referenced answer, you can remove the condition. It will look like this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'assign_tier_pricing', 90, 2 );
function assign_tier_pricing( $price, $product ) {
    $price *= 0.5; // Set all prices for simple products to 50% off.     
    return $price;   
}
```

Comment: that might be because you are not placing it in the right place. Have you included it in theme functions.php or any custom developed plugin which is activated?

Comment: in child theme functions.php